# Bizarre output when I try and print the index of my QtableWidget?

Tags: python, object, pyqt5, qtablewidget

**Background Info**

I created an instance of my QtableWidget called self.TableOBJ and I'm having trouble referencing information from it.

Right now I'm trying to select the corresponding row given an integer, but when I do this and try and print my row it returns none.

This lead me to believe how I was referencing the object was incorrect.

So I tried to access the vertical index of my QtableWidget and see if I can get any output, but when I do this it returns the following...

```
<PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x00000000047BC5F8>
```

**QUESTION**

Can anyone explain as to why the output is in this format and how to convert it to the actual index list?

And if anyone could help me selecting the row of my QtableWidget that too would be helpful.

```
def initiateMultiPlot(self, tableV, rowV, PlotV):
    """
        1. Match TableName values with the key values in our TableDB
        2. When we find a  match look at that key's corresponding Table Object, and iterate
        through that objects rows and select the rows specified by rowV
        3.Call plot for those values

    """
    f = createFIG()
    print("")
    for i in tableV:
        """
            tableV: is list of strings that represent assigned tablenames [Table1, Table2, Table3]
            rowV: is a list, containing lists representing rows from corresponding Tables the user wishes to plot.
                for example [[1,2],[3,4],[1]] means rows 1,2 from table1, rows 3,4 from table2... so on
            PlotV: is a string that is ethier "box" or "whisker" to tell what method to plot. Default right now 
            is to do a simple boxplot
        """
        print("Creating table instance")

        #Table Dictionary is setup so the names of the Tables (tableV) are the keys of the dictionary
        # and the actual table objects are referenced by these keys
        self.TableOBJ = self.TableDictionary[i]
        print("Data Type for the table object is..................{}".format(type(self.TableOBJ)))

        #for i in range(self.TableOBJ.rowCount()):
        # try:
        #     self.TableOBJ.setVerticalHeaderLabels(arange(self.TableOBJ.rowCount()))
        # except Exception as e:
        #     print(e)


        ### Test to see if I can print any output from my object###

        print((self.TableOBJ.currentIndex()))
        for j in rowV:
              for k in j:
                print("selecting rows")
                print(self.TableOBJ.selectRow(k))

                x = self.TableOBJ.selectRow(k)
                print("x data is here before plot command is issued................... {}".format(x))
                #ColHeader is the horizontal header for my QtableWidget, and is just a list of strings.
                y = self.TableOBJ.ColHeader
                f.plotData(x,y,PlotV, False)


    f.plt.show()
```

full code: https://github.com/Silvuurleaf/Data-Analysis-and-Visualization-GUI/blob/master/Plotter4.1

The problem stems around line 299 in my class MainWindow

file used to upload data:https://github.com/Silvuurleaf/Data-Analysis-and-Visualization-GUI/blob/master/Test%206.csv

Comment: Having a code where each class is entangled with another is not scalable, each class must perform a single task, that is the main concept of OOP. A class that performs a specific task is better than a class that wants to span tasks. When implementing a software, you must separate each task, and this task must be tested independently of the other parts, when you can not do that is that we are doing something wrong, since when debugging it is better to know where the problem is, and then , Debugging that part, codes that have more than 300 lines are not easy to debug.

Comment: I recommend that you create a file for each class, and the amounts in your main class, and have test code for each part and make sure it works correctly.

Comment: If I seperate the classes into their own .py file what's the best way to link the files if they need to communicate with each other?

Comment: The idea is not to communicate between classes, but their instances, ie you must create objects and link them. Each class must be independent. That's what I mean with tangled.

Comment: If you write a document in your project I could implement it so that you see how the classes should be separated.

Comment: hmm i see thanks for the advice. I'll look into what you're telling me to do and see If I can re arrange my code in a more user-friendly formatted package.

Comment: Review the following project, I did it with some of my students to see how the parts in a project should be separated: https://github.com/CodeHuntersLab/CuriElements/tree/master/CuriElements

Comment: not sure what you mean by write a document can you explain further?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151108/discussion-between-markus-t-and-eyllanesc).